# how to increase timeout in websphere console when we are consuming the WSS3 service?

Tags: websphere, wss-3.0

I need the steps in order to increase timeout in websphere console when we are consuming the WSS3 service ?

Yes but doesn't work please could you provide the steps for me in order to understand this steps
Any Assistance will be better
thank you